# how to assigning values for child window?

Tags: javascript

```
var selwindow = window.open('child1.html','_blank','resizable=yes,width='+(screen.width-500)+',height='+(screen.height-500)+'');
selwindow.document.selectform.childText.value=document.getElementById('pdetails1').value;
```

I am using this code to assign a value for textbox in the child window. It works well in Internet Explorer, but it shows an error when run in Firefox. It shows:  `selwindow.document.selectform is undefined`.

Here,  `childText` is the current window textbox id, and `pdetails1` is the child window text box id

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that selectform is the name/id of something in the page.

IE doesn't actually use JavaScript, it uses jScript.  jScript converts all names/ids into global variables, so that code works, but it won't work in anything other than IE.

Try:

```
selwindow.document.getElementById('selectform').childText.value = ...
```

if the form doesn't have an id, give it one:

```
<form id="selectform" />
```

Comment: i tried but it shown selwindow.document.getElementById('selectform') is null

Comment: what does the form tag look like?  I'm guessing `selectform` is it's name, in which case you need to set an id.

Comment: no, i changed <form id="selectform"> like this. still it shows the selwindow.document.getElementById('selectform') is null error

Comment: parent window:
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
function sendTo()
{
var selwindow = window.open('child1.html','_blank','resizable=yes,width='+(screen.width-500)+',height='+(screen.height-500)+'');
selwindow.selectform.childText=document.getElementById('pdetails1').value;
}
</SCRIPT>
<BODY >
<form name="form" method="post" action="child2.html">
<input type="text" value="" name="text1" id="pdetails1">
<input type="button" value="Next" onClick="sendTo()">
</BODY>
</HTML>
child window:
<HTML>
<form name="selectform">
<input type=text name="text5" id="childText">
</form>
</HTML>

Comment: From your comment: `<form name="selectform">` needs to be `<form name="selectform" id="selectform">`

Comment: i tried but it shown the same error please copy that above code and check it from your browser